# Where in the HTML/CSS/JavaScript is Mobile Formatting Handled?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider the following site: 200minus.com

This site looks good on both a mobile phone and a desktop.  It's as if when you view the site on a mobile phone, everything is appropriately shrunken.  Where in the source code (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) is this being dealt with (or is this typically dealt with)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres 2 typical approaches to page design in mobile/desktop situations.

- Adjust the page to suit the size of the display at load.

  or...
- Make the page respond to it's size dynamically( This is referred to as responsive design).

It is considered good form to use responsive design, as it has obvious advantages for screen resizes. Such as if a tablet/mobile was rotated or if a desktop user resized their window.

A good design should be implemented predominately in css as it is the fastest part of the page to update/ evaluate, and is simpler to implement than modifying the page style than JS. Proportional layout and forward planning help considerably when it comes to producing a layout that works well on many screen sizes and many guides will instruct you to design for mobiles first, then adjust for desktop sites. Personally I try to think of them as one part that is never a fixed size.

The bread and butter of responsive design is media queries; they allow you to only active certain css rules under one or more conditions. For example:

```
@media (min-width:650px){ 
        .about_tablet{height:175px;}
}

@media (min-width:650px) and (max-width: 675px){ /* both conditions must be met */
        .about_tablet{height:175px;}
}

@media (min-width:650px) , (max-width: 675px){ /* one or both conditions must be met */ 
        .about_tablet{height:175px;}
}
```

Another very useful trick is viewports

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
```

They can be a little strange, behaviour isn't uniform across older mobile devices and they don't work at all on desktops, but they are quite useful. You can force a page width and scale the page on a pixel by pixel basis (800 px image on a 400px wide screen for instance). Prevent the user from being able to zoom in, or limit the zoom. Most useful is the `width=device-width"` which prevents the horrible zoomed out effect you get on non optimised webpages when you view them on a phone.

If theres a more specific concept you want to talk about I'm happy to help, a vast majority of my work is done for mobiles.

Answer (score 3):

In the CSS as media queries.

You can adapt the layout of CSS styling, depending on what size the browser window it's being viewed with is.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries, and
- the official W3C documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: Edited to add a link to the official documentation, at the W3.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). Just try it out! I think it's really good. Also mentioned in the answer above this is everything done with CSS. For example this:

```
@media (min-width:768px){.container{width:750px}
}
@media (min-width:992px){.container{width:970px}
}
@media (min-width:1200px){.container{width:1170px}
}
```

When the width is smaller than 992 px the container will be set to 750px.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

In CSS using media queries, as explained here:
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

For example:

```
@media screen and max-width:600px { /* CSS here */ }
```

Is a common brakepoint that I use.

For some specific handling I've found I have to use javascript or jQuery to really get the effect I want, but generally CSS media queries and some intelligent and creative use of showing/hiding objects with the display property will get you 99% of the way there.